# Converting Racket code so that it uses only one Cond

Tags: racket, conditional-statements

*This code has many cond used in it I have to convert this code and use cond only once, which I am unable to do.*

`(define (q1a x) 
 (cond 
   [(p1? x) 
    (cond 
       [(p2? x) ’down] 
       [else ’up])] 
 [else 
   (cond [(p2? x) ’left] 
   [else ’right])]))`

**After converting the code in which I have to use cond function only once but i can use and, or I am getting this error 
Here is the error : expected a clause with a question and an answer, but found a clause with 3 parts**

```
    (define (qla x)
      (cond[(p1? x)(p2? x)'down]
       [(else 'up)]
       [(or[(p2? x)'left]
       [else 'right])]))
```

Comment: Homework questions should not be asked on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would convert your expression into a `match` statement:

```lisp
(define (q1a x)
  (match x
    [(p1? and p2?) 'down]
    [p1? 'up]
    [p2? 'left]
    [_ 'right]))
```

If you must use `cond`, you must rewrite your cond expression slightly as yours isn't a valid formulation of `cond`. You must have a statement, returning a truthy value, in each `car` of the `cond` expressions, you might write it as follows:

```lisp
(define (qla x)
  (cond
    [(and (p1? x) (p2? x)) 'down]
    [(p1? x) 'up]
    [(p2? x) 'left]
    [else 'right]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `and` will solve your woes. You're really just using `cond` like an `if` statement which, as it seems you've noticed, isn't its intended purpose. Try something like this:

```
(define (qla x)
    (cond [(and (p1? x) (p2? x)) 'down]
          [(and (p1? x) (not (p2? x)) 'up)]
          [(p2? x) 'left] ; (p1? x) must be false
          [else 'right]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want that? Since your `cond` only has one consequent term and an alternative I would have written this as nested `if`

```
(define (q1a x) 
 (if (p1? x) 
     (if  (p2? x)
          'down 
          'up) 
     (if  (p2? x)
          'left 
          'right)))
```

No matter what outcome you would never use more than two predicates so it's log(n) terms. while if you were to use one `cond` it would eb slightly less effiecent:

```
(cond ((and (p1? x) (p2? x)) 'down)
      ((p1? x) 'up) ; checking only one since the other is false
      ((p2? x) left)
      (else 'right))
```

Now as you double the number of terms you will double the average run of this while the first will only get one predicate extra if you manage to find distinguishing ways to halve the space. Often wishful thinking so you end up with something in between.